# Primes among quadratic residues modulo a prime

Tags: probability, number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-residues

Given a prime $p$, find all quadratic residues modulo $p$. We randomly select a number $n$ among these quadratic residues modulo $p$. What is the probability of $n$ being a prime as $p$ goes to infinity?

I use [A132213](http://oeis.org/A132213) and [A000224](https://oeis.org/A000224) to estimate the answer. The answer might be approximately 12%. However, I am wondering if there is a standard proof.

Comment: Given the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem), you can be sure that the answer is not a fixed value.

Comment: The number of quadratic residues in $\{1,2,\ldots,p-1\}$ mod $p$ is $(p-1)/2$. The number of these which are primes is $O(\dfrac{p}{\log p})$. So surely the probability as $p$ goes to infinity is just zero?